# How to get id from tr, then display that id in a new td, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to get all IDs of all rows in a table and then to display every ID in a new cell of the same table. How can I do that through JS? I started this script but it does not work...

```
function displayID() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].id;

  var newTd = document.getElementById("tr").insertCell(0);
    newTd.innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: hello. what do you mean by `identifier`? attr id or number of the child?

Comment: attr id, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search with **querySelectorAll** for the TR's. **Foreach** of them use **insertCell** to create a new cell and set with **textContent** the text-value to the id from the row.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(tr => {
    const td = tr.insertCell(0);
    td.textContent = tr.id;
});
```

```css
td, th, table { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row2'>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='rowExtra'>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Even simpler than using createElement is
 `const cell = tr.insertCell(0);  cell.textContent = tr.id;`

Comment: Thanks, `insertCell` was new for me. It's a little bit shorter (1 line) than `document.createElement` and `appendChild`. Also you can set the position (n-th cell).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful! My table still does not work (I guess I have to still display the final result somehow) but at least I see the right code to be used - thank you so much!